# How to obtain count of comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my Articles `index.html.erb` so far

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
    <th>Total Number of Comments Per Article</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<p>Total Number of Articles in database: <%= @count_of_articles %></p>

<h4>All Comments Written So Far</h>
<% @comments.each do |c| %>
<p><b><%= c.commenter %></b></p>
<p><%= c.body %></p>
<% end %> 


<%= link_to 'New Article', new_article_path %>
```

This is my Article's `index` action

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.all

    @count_of_articles = @articles.count

    @comments = Comment.all 

  end
```

I am trying to figure out how to place the number of comments that each article has in the `<td>Placeholder</td>`

How do I do that?

EDIT

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Comment: Can you share the model file for `Article` and `Comment`. Is there any relationship between these two?

Comment: @sureshprasanna70, have added that in EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply `count`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
    <th>Total Number of Comments Per Article</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td><%= article.comments.count %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

`article.comments` is an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) which extends the [`ActiveRecord::Calculations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) class containing the [`count` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count). The relation was defined in your model by you. Internally, ActiveRecord will call a `COUNT` SQL query to determine the number of comments that matches your article.

Comment: do you mind explaining how `comments` is found here?

Comment: thank you for a through explanation. What I really meant by how `comments` is found question ... is that I'm assuming because of their default relationship in place, that one can just say `article.comments.count`,correct?

Comment: you'll probably want to take a look at you log file for the output on that view

Comment: You're welcome. Like I said, `comments` is a relation that was defined in the model by you. ActiveRecord will infer a lot of default ways to determine the related comments to an article using a singular name of the relationship, an underscore, and the id for the foreign key column that refers to the owning entity, e.g. `article_id`. It's basic N-to-N relationship stuff using keys.

Answer (score 1):

by doing `article.comments.count` in the view you're basically running a sql query for each article in your db. Why not gather all records in your controller, and ask for the count in your view?, something like:

in the controller:

```
@comments_by_article = Comment.all.group_by(&:article_id)
```

and, in your view:

```
<td><%= @comments_by_article[article.id] && @comments_by_article[article.id].count || 0 %></td>
```

that way, rails will cache `@comments_by_article` in your controller, and you'll hitting the database once.

Comment: hey, followed your answer verbatim, and got this error `undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass``. In case I did anything wrong, this is what I did, I put `@comments_by_article = Comment.all.group_by(&:article_id)` in the index action, and then `<td><%= @comments_by_article[article.id].count %></td>` in the view.

Comment: ah ok, i forgot that maybe you can have articles without comments.... in that case you can do: <td><%= @comments_by_article[article.id] && @comments_by_article[article.id].count %></td>. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count with 
`article.comments.count`

Comment: do you mind explaining how `comments` is found here?

Comment: In order to get a full idea of how relations work please go through the documentation here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html